# system of coupled equations

Tags: differential-equations

I want to solve system of coupled equations for `b[x,t]` and `c[x,t]`:

```
D[b[t, x], t] == m D[b[t, x], x, x] + w b[t, x] c[t, x] -k b[t, x], 
D[c[t, x], t] == d D[c[t, x], x, x] + r b[t, x] c[t, x],
c[t, 1] == 1, 
Derivative[0, 1][c][t, 0] == 0,
Derivative[0, 1][b][t, 0] == 0,
Derivative[0, 1][b][t, 1] == 0
```

I used this code:

```
NDSolve[{D[b[t, x], t] == m D[b[t, x], x, x] + w b[t, x] c[t, x] -k b[t, x],
D[c[t, x], t] == d D[c[t, x], x, x] + r b[t, x] c[t, x], c[t, 1] == 1,
Derivative[0, 1][c][t, 0] == 0, Derivative[0, 1][b][t, 0]==0,Derivative[0, 1][b][t, 1]==0},
{b,c}, {t, 0, 10}, {x, 0, 1}]
```

but error is:

> Nonlinear coefficients are not supported in this version of NDSolve

Could any one help me in solving these equations?

Comment: "Nonlinear coefficients are not supported in this version of NDSolve" - it means what it says. Can you reformulate your PDE?

Comment: You also can't use symbols in numerical solver. You need actual numerical values for the parameters there (m,w,k,r....). Please post complete self contained code.

Comment: putting numbers instead of (m,k,r,w), how can I solve this coupled nonlinear equations?

Comment: putting numbers, you might still get the same error message, but at least it is a start. This way one does not have to guess what numbers to use.

Comment: I don't get what do you mean exactly by reformulating my equations.

Comment: If you fix numerically all symbolic parameters, you might try then use the option `Method -> {"MethodOfLines",  "SpatialDiscretization" ->"FiniteElement"}` which is the way around. Have a look here for details:  `http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveMethodOfLines.html#1699661144`